# Fitting table contents inside a beamer class in latex using multirow

Tags: tables, beamer, multirow

[image] I need to represent this in latex
Code
It goes outside the beamer class
[image]\begin{table}[]

```
    \AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\scriptsize}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|}\hline
        \textbf{Chatting topics:} William Shakespeare; Sun; Jane Austen\\
        \textbf{Knowledge:} ...... Shakespeare invented the names Miranda, Jessica, and Olivia. ...... \\ \hline
        
        \textbf{Dialog}\\
        ......\\
        A: Do you like shakespeare?\\
        B: Yes a little bit. He is often called england’ s national
        poet and the "bard of avon".\\
        A: He is a great dramatist that influenced a lot of people,
        like Joenesbo. \\ \hline
        
        \textbf{Response 1:} Did you know that Ronald Reagan was
        rejected for a movie role because an entertainment executive
        didn’ t look presidential enough?\\
        \textbf{Response 2:} I love shakespeare’ s works. Did you know
        that he invented the names Miranda, Jessica, and Olivia ?\\ \hline  
        
            
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete small test file that shows your problem, you ask about multirow but the fragment you post has no `\multirow`. Since the tabular is just a single column you can most likely simplify the markup by removing the tabular, also you should remove the `\resizebox` that isn't needed as the text is a known width (5cm) already there is no need to scale it to a specific width. You just need to use a suitable font size such as `\scriptsize` (which you can just use directly you don't need `\AtBeginEnvironment`.

Comment: Whether to do it using multirow or just normally we can write to get a proper view inside the frame. Sorry I am in the learning stage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the `tabular` markup was helping and certainly scaling tables rarely produces good results.

It seems to fit with the text at normal size without needing to select `\scriptsize` (which would be very hard to read in a presentation format)

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand\myrule{\par\smallskip\hrule\medskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\textbf{Chatting topics:} William Shakespeare; Sun; Jane Austen


\myrule

        \textbf{Knowledge:} ...... Shakespeare invented the names Miranda, Jessica, and Olivia. ...... 
        

\myrule
        \textbf{Dialog}        ......

        A: Do you like shakespeare?

        B: Yes a little bit. He is often called england’ s national
        poet and the "bard of avon".

        A: He is a great dramatist that influenced a lot of people,
        like Joenesbo. 

\myrule

        
        \textbf{Response 1:} Did you know that Ronald Reagan was
        rejected for a movie role because an entertainment executive
        didn’ t look presidential enough?

\myrule


        \textbf{Response 2:} I love shakespeare’ s works. Did you know
        that he invented the names Miranda, Jessica, and Olivia ?

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```